# To be able to use a variable with $ in its value as current user as well as some other user through the su command

Tags: shell-script, variable

Suppose a variable value has `$` symbol (storing path of a java inner class).

I want to process it as current user as well as some other user (assume current user to be `root` so that I need not enter password when using the `su` command).

Example:

```
path_value=/home/username/filename\$1.class

echo ${path_value}

su username -c "echo ${path_value}"
```

The result of first `echo`:

```
/home/username/filename$1.class
```

The results of the second `echo` inside of `su` command:

```
/home/username/filename.class
```

I want to use the variable such that I would be able to process it at both places with the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the value through the environment, then have the inner shell expand it. Assuming `username`'s login shell is Bourne-like¹:

```
$ export path_value=/home/username/filename\$1.class
$ su username -c 'echo "$path_value"'
/home/username/filename$1.class
```

This will work even if the variable contains quotes but will not work if the command used clears the environment. I don't think `su` should do that, but `sudo` might.

If we know that the variable can't contain single quotes², then just single-quoting  the expanded string in the inner shell would do:

```
$ path_value=/home/username/filename\$1.class
$ su username -c "echo '$path_value'"
/home/username/filename$1.class
```

(Note that the quotes are in the opposite order.)

---

<sup>¹ if `username`'s login shell is `csh` or `tcsh`, replace `echo "$path_value"` with `echo $path_value:q`; if it's `rc` or derivative, with `echo $path_value`.</sup>

<sup>² and newline characters if the user's login shell is `csh` or `tcsh`, and that it doesn't contain bytes not forming valid characters if the user's login shell is `yash`. Also beware that arguments starting with `-` or containing backslashes would be a problem with  `echo`, it's better to use `printf '%s\n'` for arbitrary data</sup>

Comment: With some `su` implementations and assuming the login shell of the user is Bourne-like, one can also do: `su username -- -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1"' sh "$path_value"`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `sudo` instead of `su`?

```
# path_value=/home/username/filename\$1.class
# echo "${path_value}"
/home/username/filename$1.class
# sudo -u username echo "${path_value}"
/home/username/filename$1.class
```

Answer (score 0):

in the second echo put your variable in single quotes - like:

```
su username -c "echo '${path_value}'"
```

That way echo interprets the content of the variable as a string and the "$"-sign is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to properly quote all expansions.  The shell will not peek inside single quoted strings.

```
path_value='/home/username/filename$1.class'
printf '%s\n' "$path_value"
```

Outputs `/home/username/filename$1.class`.

```
su username -c "printf '%s\n' '$path_value'"
```

Identical output.

In the second command, the *current* shell will expand the value of `path_value` inside tho command, as it is double quoted. The inner `printf` will then print the single quoted string.

Related:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

---

Note that `${variable}` is exactly the same as `$variable`. Adding `{...}` does not quote it in any way and is only needed if the character immediately following the expansion would otherwise be taken as part of its name, as in `"${variable}x"`.